# How to access client folder environment variable from server in heroku and only use one .env in root folder

Tags: reactjs, heroku, environment-variables

I currently have the following folder structure and will deploy in Heroku. I will remove if it's duplicated but I couldn't find proper answer

```
-Client
    -Google.js (contains CLIENT id) 
    -App.js
    -package.json
    -env
server.js
models
routers
package.json
env
```

My Google.js contains app id and env is prefixed with REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID

I have used proxy https://localhost:5000 in **Client package.json**

My server.js - I am accessing static client files here

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');    
const path = require('path')
const app = express();
require('./database');
require('dotenv').config()

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());


const users = require('/api/users');
app.use('/api/users', users);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')))
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build'))
})
-----
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

**When I have 2 env files, It runs perfectly. But when I try to run only with my server and deploy in heroku, client env cannot be accessed from server.**

I understand client and server env should be separated. But is there any way, I could ACCESS Google.js env file(present in client folder) from single env file in my root folder?

My Google.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';



const responseGoogle = (response) => {
  console.log(response);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <GoogleLogin       
    clientId={`${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID}`}
    buttonText="Login"
    onSuccess={responseGoogle}
    onFailure={responseGoogle}
    cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
  />,
  document.getElementById('googleButton')
);
```

Comment: I have the same issue... Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Whatever you use at client side isn't safe anyways.