# How to set up environment variables for client directory on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, environment-variables

I currently have the following directory structure:

```
-client
    -App.js
    -package.json
    -.env
server.js
models
routers
package.json
.env
```

I know how to set up variables in the `.env` at the root directory on Heroku, but not the ones in the `.env` at the `client` directory. Is there a way to do this?

I have used proxy in client package.json.

When I work with two dotenv files in the local environment, it runs perfectly. However, when I try to deploy in heroku, I don't know how to set up variables in the client dotenv file as the environment variables in Heroku.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257778/how-to-access-client-folder-environment-variable-from-server-in-heroku-and-only#) asks the same question, but it does not have any answer.

Comment: I have the same issue... Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @Junaid I ended up destroying the client directory and moving everything inside it at the root. Deploying two heroku apps, one each for client and server, also works

Answer (score -1):

[image]

1. Login to heroku
2. select the project
3. got to settings tab
4. there you can find Config Vars
   add key ,value
   Ex:- Key APP_PORT , Value 8000
   in codebase you can access this by
   process.env.APP_PORT

Comment: I know how to add config vars on Heroku. That's not my question at all. I asked how to add config vars specifically for the client directory.

Comment: we cannot specify by directory wise. we have to add config vars for root only 
or else change the key names which are going to be use in client directory

Comment: Yes, that is my question. But I don't think your solutions work. If I add config vars for root only, the client directory cannot access them. I doubt that simply changing the key names will work. I guess your answer is that it's impossible.

Comment: No We can Access in  any file inside directory by process.env.KEy

Comment: No, as you can see from my directory structure, there are two package.json files. In other words, the `process` accessed from inside `client/` directory and `process` accessed from outside `client/` directory are different. For the client directory, the root is defined as `client/` so it looks for `.env` inside `client/` so it cannot access the env variables defined in the root env file. You can try it yourself.

Comment: This post author is experiencing the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62257778/how-to-access-client-folder-environment-variable-from-server-in-heroku-and-only#